Postgres: psql login with gcloud auth and zsh throwing an error
The following works fine in bash:
PGPASSWORD=$(gcloud sql generate-login-token) psql -h xx.xxx.xx.xxx -U user@domain.com --no-password dbname

It fails in my preferred shell zsh:
zsh: parse error near `time'

What's the syntax here for zsh?

zsh uses the same syntax. Does the output of gcloud sql generate-login-token give a clue as to why it may throw that error?

No, in bash and zsh it works and appropriately creates a token.

I don't see time in the command. Is it part of what gcloud sql generate-login-token creates?

Is there anything that might have assigned aliases or such to some of the names, like oh-my-zsh? You can try running it in a clean zsh instance with /usr/bin/env -i /bin/zsh -f (that'll require absolute names for the executables or setting the PATH on the command line).

Must be. I took your advice and did zsh -f and it works fine, so some aliasing somewhere is goofing things up. Thank you.

There is no time in your command. You could turn on set -x before running to command, to see what's going on. Perhaps you have some precmd function active, which causes the problem. Also doublecheck whether psql is really what you think it is (do a type psql to find out).
